# Ways of implementing a greedy algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph

So, I have an assignment that I have to represent both adjacent and incidence matrixes statically and then, use a greedy algorithm to find the shortest path (I guess that it can be lowest cost as well, not sure) that goes through all vertices having 1 as origin.

Here's an image of the graph:

[image]

I'm kinda lost on how to do it, could somebody please give me some tips?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm

Comment: Greedy means taking the path per junction with the "best" cost.  Here I guess that is lowest.  Question - if the arrows do indeed mean only 1 direction of movement possible, "1" cannot be reached from "4" or "2" at all.  And if we take into account the greedy cost, then it cannot be reached from anywhere as 3->1 is the highest cost of all the 3 travel nodes.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for your help!

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Except 1 is the origin. So the greedy path is 15342.

Comment: correct - missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greedy Algorithm:

```
While (Not at node 1)
{
  if already visited current node, fail.
  look at all current node's exit costs and choose the lowest as next destination.
  go to next location.
}
success.
```